# Call a single function on two different methods with hooks

Tags: php, hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

So I'm wanting to shorten my code down a bit and I would like some assistance.. How can I shorten the following methods into a single register method? They both have `add_action` which is a WordPress hook, so I wasn't aware how that is possible but someone might be able to assist me.

Both functions used separately work great, just wanted to see if there was a more efficient way.

Here are the two methods:

```
/**
 * Register template
 */
public static function register_templates() {
    add_filter('single_template', function($single_template) {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_type == 'profile') {
            $single_template = '/Users/smajlovs/Sites/newsacfoodies/htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/sacfoodies/profile-template.php';
        }

        return $single_template;
    });
}

/**
 * Register Styles
 */
public static function register_styles()
{
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        global $post;

        if (is_page('foodies')) {
            wp_register_style('profile-style', content_url() . '/mu-plugins/sacfoodies/styles/profile-card.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('profile-style');
        }

        return;
    });
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're hoping for, but all you can really do is just move the code from one function into the other. `global $post` is also not doing anything, so removing that will save you a couple of lines:

```
/**
 * Register template
 */
public static function register_styles_templates() {
    add_filter('single_template', function($single_template) {
        if ($post->post_type == 'profile') {
            $single_template = '/Users/smajlovs/Sites/newsacfoodies/htdocs/wp-content/mu-plugins/sacfoodies/profile-template.php';
        }

        return $single_template;
    });

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        if (is_page('foodies')) {
            wp_register_style('profile-style', content_url() . '/mu-plugins/sacfoodies/styles/profile-card.css');
            wp_enqueue_style('profile-style');
        }

        return;
    });
}
```

Comment: Duhh, totally forgot I can do that - Thanks Jacob!